# WPF Popup wrapping when dragging vertically

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I have a project that uses a System.Windows.Controls.Primatives.Popup to drag a 'tooltip' like control along with a mouse.

Whenever the drag crosses a horizontal line the popup 'wraps' to the bottom of the screen - despite having sane values for the VerticalOffset.  The point at which this wrapping occurs appears to be tied to the HEIGHT of the window, but not it's position.

Here's the code from the sandbox project I have created that also exhibits the same behavior:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MainGrid.MouseDown += Grid_MouseDown;
            this.MainGrid.MouseUp += Grid_MouseUp;
            this.MainGrid.MouseMove += (s, e) => { if (this.Popup.IsOpen) { Popup_Drag(s, e); } };
            this.Popup.MouseMove += Popup_Drag;
        }

        private void Popup_Drag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Popup.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition(this.Popup).X;
            Popup.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition(this.Popup).Y;

            this.Status_Top.Text = String.Format("Height/Top: {0}/{1} Width/Left: {2}/{3}", this.Height, this.Top, this.Width, this.Left);
            this.Status.Text = String.Format("Vertical Offset: {0}  Horizontal Offset: {1}", Popup.VerticalOffset, Popup.HorizontalOffset);
        }

        private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Popup.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Popup.IsOpen = true;
            Popup_Drag(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

And the Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="Purple">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Status_Top"></TextBlock>
        <Popup x:Name="Popup" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsOpen="True">
            <TextBlock Background="Blue" Foreground="White">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Status">TEXT</TextBlock></TextBlock>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding `Placement="RelativePoint"` to the Popup attributes.  Apparently this is the default in Silverlight, but not WPF.